# Java mail getInputStream left recipient

Tags: inputstream, jakarta-mail

i'm writing a mail send method with javamail.
I can not understand why I get and error as: Recipient not set.
This is my code:

```
public static void sendMail(String to, String subj, String body, String attachmentName, byte[] attachment, String mime) throws Exception {
    Properties p = System.getProperties();
    Session session = Session.getInstance(p);
    MimeMessage dummyMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    dummyMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(LovProvider.getOpzioni().get("mail.address")));
    dummyMessage.setSubject(subj);
    String[] tos = to.split(";");
    Address[] tosAddr = new InternetAddress[tos.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tos.length; i++) {
        tosAddr[i] = new InternetAddress(tos[i]);
    }
    dummyMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, tosAddr);
    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    MimeBodyPart bp = new MimeBodyPart();
    bp.setText(body);
    mp.addBodyPart(bp);
    if (attachmentName != null && attachment != null) {
        DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment, mime);
        MimeBodyPart attachBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        attachBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
            attachBodyPart.setFileName(attachmentName);
            mp.addBodyPart(attachBodyPart);
        }
        dummyMessage.setContent(mp);
        //***** DEBUGGING here I find the recipient
        sendMail(dummyMessage.getInputStream());
    }

    public static void sendMail(InputStream emlFile) throws Exception {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.host", LovProvider.getOpzioni().get("mail.out.host"));
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", LovProvider.getOpzioni().get("mail.out.protocol"));
        props.put("mail." + LovProvider.getOpzioni().get("mail.out.protocol") + ".port", LovProvider.getOpzioni().get("mail.out.port"));
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, PasswordAuthentication.getAuth(LovProvider.getOpzioni().get("mail.out.user"), LovProvider.getOpzioni().get("mail.out.password")));
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession, emlFile);
        //***** DEBUGGING here I CAN NOT find the recipient
        Transport.send(message);
    }
```

As I wrote in comments in debug mode i can see the recipient correctly set in the first part, whant i convert it to InputStream to the second method I can not find recipient anymore.

Comment: I found, i should use the MimeMessage writeTo to an outputstream than create a new InputStream. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't debugging your code, but maybe this examples can help you:
Examples about sending/receiving mail via/from gmail

http://famulatus.com/component/search/?searchword=gmail&searchphrase=all&Itemid=9999

Comment: Thank you, i found the solution. I had to use writeTo MimeMessage method instead of getInputStream.